# Unreal Engine 5 foliage paint not working

Tags: unreal

I just learned unreal engine 5 and right now is trying the foliage paint.
So I'm having difficulty of making the foliage paint to work, here is the video:
https://youtu.be/oWrE8-JBdOo

as you can see, i believe i have done everything right but the tree's aren't showing up.

anyone know why ?
thankyou !